# RegEx for Tracking Numbers

Tags: android, regex

This is a pretty odd question but I was unable to find a concrete answer.

I'm making an Android app that takes in a tracking number and then determines which API (FedEx/USPS) to use.

The code I have for the regex looks like this:

```
    String USPSPattern1 = "/\\b((420 ?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d ?)?(91|94|01|03|04|70|23|13)\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d( ?\\d\\d)?)\\b/i";
    String USPSPattern2 = "/\\b((M|P[A-Z]?|D[C-Z]|LK|EA|V[A-Z]|R[A-Z]|CP|CJ|LC|LJ) ?\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d ?[A-Z]?[A-Z]?)\\b/i";

    String FedExPattern1 = "/\\b((96\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d|96\\d\\d|\\d\\d\\d\\d) ?\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d( ?\\d\\d\\d)?)\\b/i";

    if(trackingNum.matches(USPSPattern1) || trackingNum.matches(USPSPattern2))
    {
        Log.d("USPS", "TRACKING NUMBER IS USPS");
        mListener.onTrackingNumberSelected(trackingNum,1);
    }

    if(trackingNum.matches(FedExPattern1))
    {
        Log.d("FEDEX", "TRACKING NUMBER IS FEDEX");
        mListener.onTrackingNumberSelected(trackingNum,2);
    }

    else
    {
        Log.d("INVALID", "TRACKING NUMBER IS NEITHER USPS OR FEDEX");
        mListener.onTrackingNumberSelected(trackingNum,0);
    }
```

I am testing using a valid USPS number but for some reason the regex is not matching. Anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Can you include some test cases?

Answer (score 0):

A few tips to start out with.

1. Use the {} operator. It'll make your life simpler. Instead of `\\d\\d\\d\\d`, use `\\d{4}`
2. I'm not sure why you are starting with a `/`

Hopefully those two things will make the pattern clearer, and allow you to figure out where your issue is.